# Multiple Textures on a Single Face/Plane

Tags: three.js, textures, texture-mapping

If I have a geometry, say

```
THREE.PlaneGeometry(400,400);
```

or

```
THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials)});
//multiple textures on only one face
```

How would I make it so  that I have multiple textures on the same side of the plane?

Furthermore, how would I go about setting the coordinates of the texture and position of the texture on the Plane (or face)?

It should look something like this:
[image: plane_and_textures]

Comment: `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials)})` : you cannot use a material as a texture (also `MeshFaceMaterial` is now `MultiMaterial`). In r72 this line would be : `THREE.MultiMaterial(materials)`.

Comment: when I use THREE.MultiMaterial or THREE.MeshFaceMaterial, I get an error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visible' of undefined               three.min.js:496

Comment: 'visible' is a property of 'material'. 'MultiMaterial' is an array of materials

Comment: So, how does that solve that problem?

Comment: I added that comment to your question because you could face another problem if you kept that syntax. mlkn's answer is correct, you can upvote/validate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [shader material with textures as uniforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287547/multiple-transparent-textures-on-the-same-mesh-face-in-three-js) or look other approaches [there](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/533), [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087620/three-js-tile-which-has-multiple-textures-using-plane-geometry) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16781064/three-js-multiple-materials-on-object-loaded-via-objmtlloader).