# Verification of using multiple textures with three.js cubes

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Can someone please verify the following code for three.js r53?

It's taken from this question: [How to use multiple materials in a Three.js cube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820591/how-to-use-multiple-materials-in-a-three-js-cube)

I tried this code and a few variations but I don't get visible cubes.  My texture images are named as they should be.

```
var materials = [];

for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = i + '.png';
  var tex = new THREE.Texture(img);
  img.tex = tex;

  img.onload = function() {
      this.tex.needsUpdate = true;
  };

  var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, map: tex});
  materials.push(mat);
}

var cubeGeo = new THREE.CubeGeometry(400, 400, 400, 1, 1, 1, materials);
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial());
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
var cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 400, 400, 400, 1, 1, 1 );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeo, materials );
```

`materials` is an array of 6 three.js materials, one for each face.

See the Migration Guide: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide.

EDIT: `CubeGeometry` has been renamed to `BoxGeometry` and `THREE.MeshFaceMaterial` has been deprecated.

three.js r.92

Comment: Also CubeGeometry renamed to BoxGeometry (r66)

Answer (score 0):

THREE.CubeGeometry() doesn't support a list of materials. I thought it did too, but if you check the current source code.... it doesn't