# Change color of 3D Cube created using Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Help! How do you change the colors of a 3D cube from the defaults in the `Three.js` examples?

Here is what I have so far -

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

**JS**

```
// revolutions per second
var angularSpeed = 0.2;
var lastTime = 0;

// this function is executed on each animation frame
function animate() {
  // update
  var time = (new Date()).getTime();
  var timeDiff = time - lastTime;
  var angleChange = angularSpeed * timeDiff * 2 * Math.PI / 1000;
  cube.y += angleChange;
  lastTime = time;

  // render
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  // request new frame
  requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    animate();
  });
}

// renderer
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(container.offsetWidth, container.offsetHeight);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// camera
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 
                 window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 700;

// scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// cube Length, Height, Width
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(400, 100, 200), 
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          wireframe: true,
          color: '#ff0000'
}));
cube.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.1;
cube.rotation.y = Math.PI * 0.3;
scene.add(cube);

// start animation
animate();
```

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpXrv/) is a Fiddle for it.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252592/how-to-change-face-color-in-three-js

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820591/how-to-use-multiple-materials-in-a-three-js-cube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MeshNormalMaterial` doesn't support  either `color` or `Ambient` properties which are used to manipulate the colors of materials

so just use  `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xFF0000})`  with the `color` property set.

or you can use `setHex` function on the material afterwards to change the material's `color` that was previously created.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpXrv/1/) for a demo

Comment: Thanks!!! It worked, One more question, Like you are changing color click, can we change the the dimension also??? I have posted this question in SO http://stackoverflow.com/q/21783976/2719346 Can you please look int it??

Answer (score 1):

in this bit:

`var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(400, 100, 200), 
      new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          wireframe: true,
          color: '#ff0000'`

change the MeshBasicMaterial color to the hexcode of the color you want

I'm still trying to get the simple cube example they showed to even load on my browser though...

Answer (score 0):

When WIreframe is set to true the color property is taken by the line or vertices of the cube, remove wireframe:true you will get the color of cube...