# Change width/height/length of 3D Cube created with Three.js at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

Can we change the dimension "width/height/length" of 3D Cube created with Three.js at runtime?

Like I got a Fiddle in SO which changes Color of Cube at run time : **http://jsfiddle.net/mpXrv/1/**

Similarly can we change the Dimension??

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<div class="inputRow clear" id="dimensionsNotRound" data-role="tooltip">
    <label class="grid-8">Dimensions (mm):</label>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div> <span>Length</span>

        <input class="numeric-textbox" type="text" value="">
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div> <span>Width</span>

        <input class="numeric-textbox" type="text" value="">
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div> <span>Height</span>

        <input class="numeric-textbox" type="text" value="">
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <button id="btn">Click me to change the Dimensions</button>
```

**JS**

```
    //Script for 3D Box 


// revolutions per second
var angularSpeed = 0.2;
var lastTime = 0;

// this function is executed on each animation frame
function animate() {
    // update
    var time = (new Date()).getTime();
    var timeDiff = time - lastTime;
    var angleChange = angularSpeed * timeDiff * 2 * Math.PI / 1000;
    cube.rotation.y += angleChange;
    lastTime = time;

    // render
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // request new frame
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        animate();
    });
}

// renderer
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(container.offsetWidth, container.offsetHeight);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


// camera
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 700;

// scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// cube
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(400, 100, 200), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: '#cccccc'
}));
cube.overdraw = true;
cube.rotation.x = Math.PI * 0.1;
cube.rotation.y = Math.PI * 0.3;
scene.add(cube);

// add subtle ambient lighting
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x888888);
scene.add(ambientLight);

// directional lighting
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x666666);
directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
scene.add(directionalLight);

// start animation
animate();
```

Here is the Fiddle for the same! **http://jsfiddle.net/EtSf3/1/**

Let me know if you need any other information.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution 1 (better)**

You must use the scale mesh property to increase (or decrease) the dimensions of your object.

http://jsfiddle.net/EtSf3/4/

First, You need to set your `cube` variable to the global scope.

I've replaced the dimensions of your cube to 1, 1, 1.

```
cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(1, 1, 1), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: '#cccccc'
}));
```

Attach an even on the btn

```
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

$('btn').onclick = function() {
    var width = parseInt($('inp-width').value),
        height = parseInt($('inp-height').value),
        length = parseInt($('inp-length').value);

    cube.scale.x = width;
    cube.scale.y = height;
    cube.scale.z = length;
};
```

**Solution 2**

An other solution will be to delete your object and create a new mesh with the given values.

Comment: You Rock Man!!! I think Solution 1 will work for me!! looks simple, easy and Quick... Thank you so much!!!

Comment: In the fiddle its working fine!!!... but when I incorporated the changes in my code, its throwing error "Cannot call method 'change' of null"... any idea why??

Comment: Hi, I have added my solution in your answer... please review and let me know if this is a correct approach.. if yes, why its not working in Fiddle?

Comment: Can you also look into this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788385/setting-new-dimension-using-jquery-or-javascript-for-cylindergeometry-from-three

Answer (score 1):

What you want is Mesh.scale (cube.scale in you example).

http://jsfiddle.net/EtSf3/3/

This is the code that I added

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('numeric-textbox');
    cube.scale.x = parseFloat(inputs[0].value) || cube.scale.x;
    cube.scale.z = parseFloat(inputs[1].value) || cube.scale.z;
    cube.scale.y = parseFloat(inputs[2].value) || cube.scale.y;
});
```

Comment: When I change  the dimensions and click the button, the Fiddle stop working... Am I doing somthing wrong??

Comment: I got this error in Console: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://jobs.jsfiddle.net/random.js?callback=Request.JSONP.request_map.request_0
THREE.WebGLRenderer
THREE.WebGLRenderer 57 three.min.js:386

Comment: Thank you for looking!!! Appreciate It! Though not sure why its throwing the error... but "Paul Rad-Dupuy's" Solution worked for me... Thanks once again