# Error involved in displaying images on a shape using Three.js

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender

I am trying to display images on each face of the polyhedron using three.js r71. I am making the geometry by loading a JSON file which holds the data that defines the shape. I set a plane below the polyhedron as well. I get an error and I'm wondering what this means or what I am doing wrong. Here is the error message I get in the JavaScript console:

> [.WebGLRenderingContext-0888D200]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION :
> glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1
>
> WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this  context.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var four;

var meshFour;

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

function init() {
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xEEEEEE, 1.0));
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
    var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(60, 40, 1, 1);
    var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
    plane.receiveShadow = true;
    plane.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
    plane.position.x = 0;
    plane.position.y = 0;
    plane.position.z = 0;

    //LOADING GEOMETRY
    var loaderFour = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    var materialsArray = [];
    materialsArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("./resources/images/IPT.PNG")}));
    materialsArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("./resources/images/Alerts.png")}));
    materialsArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("./resources/images/action-item-tracking.png")}));
    materialsArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("./resources/images/admin.png")}));
    
    for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        materialsArray[i].map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    }
    loaderFour.load("./resources/json/tetrahedron-try.json", function (model) {

        var materialFour = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materialsArray);

        four = new THREE.Mesh(model, materialFour);//issue according to three.js
        four.translateY(1);
        four.scale = new THREE.Vector3(3, 3, 3);
        meshFour = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(four, materialFour);
        scene.add(four);
    });

    camera.position.x = 20;
    camera.position.y = 20;
    camera.position.z = 20;
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    
    var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
    spotLight.position.set(-40, 60, 10);
    spotLight.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(spotLight);
    scene.add(plane);


    document.getElementById("WebGL-output").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    render();
    
    function render() {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    
}

window.onload = init();
```

The JSON file code is here:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "type": "Geometry",
        "vertices": 4,
        "uvs": 1,
        "faces": 4,
        "generator": "io_three",
        "version": 3,
        "normals": 4
    },
    "uvs": [[0.250046,0.433025,0.749954,0.433025,0.5,0.865958,0.999907,0.865957,9.3e-05,0.865957,0.5,9.3e-05]],
    "faces": [40,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2,40,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,40,3,0,2,4,0,2,3,0,2,40,3,1,0,5,1,0,3,1,0],
    "normals": [-0.471389,-0.333323,0.816492,-0.471389,-0.333323,-0.816492,0.942808,-0.333323,0,0,1,0],
    "vertices": [-2.42416,0,4.19877,-2.42416,-0,-4.19877,4.84832,0,-0,-0,6.85655,-0],
    "name": "Tetrahedron.001Geometry.3"
}
```

Comment: maybe because you are assigning texture maps to your material but your object does not have UV coords.

Comment: What are UV coordinates? What do they do?

Comment: If you google "What are UV coordinates?" you will get plenty of info. Basically they are coords that define how the texture is applied to the object.

Comment: From what I've read, the texture is the image I would apply to the shape which from what I read, I should be doing in the 3-D software; but in the JavaScript I am trying to dynamically display the image on each side of the shape. Eventually I want to display an image that corresponds to the choice a user selects, being a check box choice. Am I doing this in the correct way?Apply a texture through the Blender program using the UV tools they have, save it; and then use my code to display images dynamically (whether it is hard coded or depending on user's input) on top of that shape that I saved?

Comment: Once you have the UV coords computed you can dynamically change the texture of your faces.

Comment: It seems like the shape is generated after the UV coords have been put in; but it seems to show the native texture I applied to the shape within my 3D program Blender. So in this case, for explanation purposes, I have a tetrahedron with an image of a cat broken up all over it, but my code doesn't display the four different images (each image being on one face). Perhaps the way I'm creating these UV coordinates inside Blender isn't correct. Or perhaps it could be the JavaScript code not displaying the images. No error/warning has come up in my JavaScript console however.

Comment: You would need to create separate UV coords per face. Just like you have 4 sets of normal coords defined.

Comment: I've generated my UV coordinates and have updated the JSON data in the post, but the JavaScript code doesn't seem to display the faces and the console doesn't have any errors. Do you still think it could be the UV coordinates? I'm not sure you could tell easily by just looking at the JSON file, but maybe you have an idea.

Comment: so I assume that know you don't get the error message you have at the top of your post?

Comment: That's correct, yea. No error.

Comment: great. so we fixed one problem. for the second problem would it it be possible for you to create a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pnasL9pa/11/, I'm afraid I can't get any of the WebGL to create the scene itself in jsFiddle, at least on my local environment I can get the shape to show... Sorry I posted days after your last post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your json file you have `"uvs": 1` which is in accordance with the images I get:

[image] [image]

so you are only applying one texture to two faces, according to the uv's.
So again the issue is with your model creation method.

Here is my version of the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/dfnkhbjm/), which yes doesn't work because of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` problem. If you copy it local, it should work.

Comment: I have altered my model creation method ( I replaced the json file with a newer one ) and copied your JavaScript. I get more promising results in that it isn't one image over two faces but one image per face, but the image is always the same; it being the very first one in the array.

Comment: Have you updated this `http://intelitrac.com/tetrahedron-third.json` because I am still seeing the old version.

Comment: Try clearing browser cache; I'm pretty sure I replaced it. Let me know if that doesn't do it.

Comment: something is not computed correctly. Add `for( var i = 0; i < model.faces.length; i++ ) { model.faces[i].materialIndex = i; }` inside the loader.load code before you add the `four` to the scene.

Comment: Thank you; that worked. What is the for loop specifically doing?

Comment: assigning which material to use from your materials array on which face. You should make sure that `materialsArray.length === model.faces.length`

Comment: I'm getting a new type of error for a different shape I made after making the UV coordinates... I was wondering if you could tell just by the errors being given if it is a code issue or a issue with the shape I made in my 3D program.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined
(325)three.js:21430 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transparent' of undefined
(5293)three.js:21430 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transparent' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but it is somehow related to the 71th version. The problem is solved in the more decent 72th version despite the fact that it is still not on release. Check here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6774.

You can find the 72th version [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev).

Comment: Thank you for that; that will help in future postings in jsFiddle.