# Raycasting hard-faces of a mesh -- Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

i created a box in three.js

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 100, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.set(5, 5, 10);

var geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5,2,5);

var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0ff0, wireframe:false, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geo, mat);
scene.add(mesh);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

After that i want to raycast to cubes faces which mouse over on.Thus i created this function

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function onMouseMove( event ) {
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;     

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );   

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( mesh);

    for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
        intersects[ i ].face.color.setHex( 0xDDC2A3);
        mesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
    }

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
```

It **nearly** works correct. i mean, it changes color of the half of the face. You know, the mesh which created by `BoxGeometry()` has 12 `Face3`. I want  **the complete face** or **hard-face** or **`Face4`** which took shape by `Face3+Face3`. Any idea how i can accomplish this?

Comment: For box you can loop `geometry.faces` and find all faces with same face normal direction as your selected.

Comment: @uhura too hackey for me

Comment: @uhura's answer is pretty decent imo. There isn't a magic method for finding/selecting faces. You'll either need to A) loop through faces and determine those that need to be selected, B) precompute a map of face-indices in the structure you need them, or C) build your box using 6 separate meshes (one for each side.)

Btw Face4 was removed from ThreeJS.

Comment: Face4 is removed? I was thinking about adding a Face4 into source code until i saw your comment. I wonder why it was removed thou.

Comment: @jjkk Yep, from ThreeJS r59 -> r60 "Face4 is removed. Use 2 Face3 to emulate it." ... I'm not sure why exactly, I think generally 3D Graphics libraries/hardware are optimized for triangular faces in geometry. Perhaps the developers thought Face4 too much of a burden given that anything you can do with Face4 you can also do with Face3. (except in the case of your specific example, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only works for ready-built, non-Buffer geometries like .. BoxGeometry, SphereGeometry, CircleGeometry etc...

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( mesh);

for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {

    var faceIndex = intersects[i].faceIndex;

    if(faceIndex == 0 || (faceIndex % 2) == 0) {
        intersects[i].object.geometry.faces[faceIndex].color.setHex( 0xD1B3B3);
        intersects[i].object.geometry.faces[faceIndex + 1].color.setHex( 0xD1B3B3);
        intersects[i].object.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;

    }else {
        intersects[i].object.geometry.faces[faceIndex].color.setHex( 0xD1B3B3);
        intersects[i].object.geometry.faces[faceIndex - 1].color.setHex( 0xD1B3B3);
        intersects[i].object.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
    }

}

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your specific example, given that you're using a default box-geometry and we know that there are 2 faces per side, wrapped in a specific direction/order, you should be able to pair each of the two faces together like so:

```
var facesPerSide = 2;
for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
    var side = Math.floor(intersects[i].faceIndex/facesPerSide);
    for(var j=0;j<facesPerSide;j++) {
        mesh.geometry.faces[side*facesPerSide+j].color.setHex(0xDDC2A3);
    }
    mesh.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
}
```

Edit: Obviously it would get a bit more complex if using a variable number of segments for width/height/depth, or if using non-platonic solid geometry.